# Kotlin smart cast to non-nullable type and ::class syntax not working together as expected

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection, null, nullable

I'm trying to understand what's going on with the following code snippet (extracted from a larger project), in which I manipulate a value returned from a Java superclass.
The value has type `T`, unbounded in Java, so it is mapped (I guess) to a platform type `T!` which I am treating as if it where a `T?`.

```kotlin
when (val value = node.getConcentration(molecule)) { // it's a Java method returning an unbounded generic T
    is Number -> value.toDouble()
    is String -> value.toDouble()
    is Time -> value.toDouble()
    null -> 0.0 // null has been ruled out, now Kotlin should smart-cast
    else -> throw IllegalStateException(
        "Expected a numeric value in $molecule at node ${node.id}, " +
            "but $value of type ${value::class.simpleName} was found"  // THIS IS THE RELEVANT LINE
    )
}
```

I would expect this to work, but I get an error on the type lookup:
`Expression in a class literal has a nullable type 'T', use !! to make the type non-nullable`. It looks to me like Kotlin does not understand that since the `null` case has ben ruled out, the runtime type must be a subclass of `Any`.

However, it gets stranger:

```kotlin
when (val value = node.getConcentration(molecule)) {
    is Number -> value.toDouble()
    is String -> value.toDouble()
    is Time -> value.toDouble()
    null -> 0.0 // null has been ruled out, now Kotlin should smart-cast
    else -> throw IllegalStateException(
        "Expected a numeric value in $molecule at node ${node.id}, " +
            "but $value of type ${value!!::class.simpleName} was found" // THIS IS THE RELEVANT LINE
    )
}
```

This compiles, but besides being ugly, this one raises (correctly, IMHO) a warning:
`Unnecessary non-null assertion (!!) on a non-null receiver of type T` -- but this means that the smart casting is work as expected!

I am currently solving as follows:

```kotlin
when (val value = node.getConcentration(molecule)) { 
    is Number -> value.toDouble()
    is String -> value.toDouble()
    is Time -> value.toDouble()
    null -> 0.0
    else -> throw IllegalStateException(
        "Expected a numeric value in $molecule at node ${node.id}, " +
            "but $value of type ${value.let { it::class.simpleName }} was found"
    )
}
```

This one compiles with no warning, and it is all in all a tolerable amount of boilerplate, but I can't find any reason for `value::class.simpleName` for raising errors, especially given that if I enforce non-nullability I get an expected warning.

Does anyone understand what's going on here?
Is this a bug in Kotlin? I could not find any specific reference to this issue
(by the way I'm on 1.4.21).

Comment: The example can be simplified to remove the Java superclass, when statement, and function call. They don't appear to affect it: https://pl.kotl.in/MSzE8jLUE This looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: Will it work if you explicitly specify type of `value` as `Any?`?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I thought it might have been caused by interaction with platform types, but your snippet actually shows the behavior is pure Kotlin. Thanks!
I think I'll open a bug report.

Comment: The bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44570

Comment: Actually a duplicate of an existing bug, and yes it is actually a compiler bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-37878

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your code like this to separate the null check on the value outside of the `when` statement, avoid the warnings and also to have cleaner code:

```
val value = node.getConcentration(molecule)?.let { value ->
    when (value) {
        is Number,
        is String,
        is Time -> value.toDouble()
        else -> throw IllegalStateException(
            "Expected a numeric value in $molecule at node ${node.id}, " +
                "but $value of type ${value} was found"
        )
    }
} ?: 0.0
```

Comment: Sure, this is doable, but it does not really shed light on the reason why the compiler complains when I use the first syntax. 
I disagree on cleanliness, I find dealing with `null` just as I do for any other value is cleaner, but that's matter of taste.